# Name of checklist for evaluation of quality of software engineering job

Tags: job-offer, work-environment

Not sure if this is on topic here, but if feels very close.

I was once browsing job offers and I came across one here at SO that had a checklist of desirable features in a software development job/team.

It was something like xxxxx's test, or xxxxx's checklist, and I think xxxxx was the name of the person who came up with the checklist.

One of the desirable features was one-command build, and another was quiet place to develop and focus.

I can't seem to find the specific name, so I can't research it again.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're almost certainly thinking of the [Joel Test](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2000/08/09/the-joel-test-12-steps-to-better-code/) by [Joel Spolsky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joel_Spolsky), the co-founder of Stack Overflow.

Comment: That list is from year 2000 and might be outdated. Moreover, I'd bet that most companies would not even meet that bar in 2000. Companies which do meet that bar (like Google perhaps), would be very selective in their interview process. That is, most engineers would not get jobs there. So, I wonder if there is a more recent guide and which also considers the average engineer.

Comment: If you search around for "Joel Test," several bloggers have commented on the extent to which it applies today, and many have offered suggestions for updates to meet modern developer expectations.

Comment: It's really not that high a bar, there's nothing magical about it, it's (deliberately) quite basic. Though it very definitely needs updating - as many have observed, and many have done just that.